# Ruby - print result of inject sum on array

Tags: arrays, ruby, sum

Part of the code below sums the elements of an array. How can I print the resulting sum of the array?

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

a = [ 1, 2, 3, 4]
b = a.map { |x| x*x }
c = a.select { |x| x%2== 0 }

puts a.inject do | sum,x |
    sum + x
end


puts a.inspect
puts b.inspect
puts c.inspect
```

Answer (score 2):

The sum of `a` can be printed by wrapping the whole `inject` block in parenthesis, making the resulting output the argument of `puts`:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]

puts (
  a.inject do |sum, x|
    sum + x
  end
)

# => 10
```

The above can be cleaned up a bit by assigning the sum of the array to a more descriptive variable, and/or by using the shorter inject syntax for summing. Your code could then look something like this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = a.map { |x| x * x }
c = a.select { |x| x % 2 == 0 }

sum_a = a.inject(:+)

puts a.inspect
puts b.inspect
puts c.inspect
puts sum_a

# => [1, 2, 3, 4]
# => [1, 4, 9, 16]
# => [2, 4]
# => 10
```

Hope it helps!

**Update:**

As Cary pointed out in the comment below, additional improvements include condensing the `c` variable assignment to use `a.select(&:even?)` for filtering out integers divisible by 2, and using `p [variable]` instead of `puts [variable].inspect`.

Comment: Parentheses are not needed if it's on one line: `puts a.inject { |sum, x| sum + x } #=> 10` or `puts a.inject(:+)`. Consider also `c = a.select(&:even?)` and `p a` rather than `puts a.inspect`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks for the feedback - I've added an update section to my answer to reflect your excellent suggestions.